# asp.net dropdown list value disappear when I clicked submit button C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem with dropdown list.

When I select one value in dropdown and I click on submmit button, after that, selected value is disappearing. But, I reload this page, selected value is appearing. I don't the  reload page - I use PostBack.

**.aspx page:**

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl1" runat="server" Height="18px" Width="172px" AutoPostBack="true"  DataTextField="Name1" DataValueField="Value1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged" TabIndex="5" >
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        dt = np.GetData();
        ddl1.DataSource = np.GetData(); //stored procedure
        ddl1.DataTextField = "Name1";
        ddl1.DataValueField = "Value1";
        ddl1.DataBind();
        ddl1.Items.Insert(0, "");
        ddl1.EnableViewState = true;
}
```

Comment: remove `DataTextField="Name1"` &  `DataValueField="Value1"` attribute from Dropdownlist tag.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava why?

Comment: I removed. It is same, it doesn't work.

Comment: is this the complete code in your `Page_Load`, what is happening inside  `ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged` will it triggered when the button is pressed

Comment: With ddl1_SelectedIndexChanged I connect other dropdown ddl2 (cascading-dropdown)